# A question on First Order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I've recently begun to tutor friends in math.  I've only tutored classes that I've taken [algebra-multivariable calculus], and last night I was tutoring a friend in calc II. He pulled out a take home quiz, and I kind of gawked at it for a minute or two, because it was over differential equations (use Euler's method with a given time step to estimate the function, solve the function using the method of separable differential equations, calculate the error). So, I haven't taken differential equations, nor did we cover them when I took calc II, so I had a bit of a crash course in it, and I wanted to check to see if I understood what I was doing (read: I have no confidence that I did this right. I read the theorems, looked at practice problems, and decided to wing it). The problem was as follows:
$$y'(t)=2-3y,\ y(0)=1 \text{ on } [0,2] \text{ with } \Delta t=.5$$
The first part was to estimate $y(2)$ using Euler's method: $u_{k + 1} = u_k + f(t_k, u_k) \cdot \Delta t$ where $f(t_k, u_k) = 2-3y$, and $k \in \{0, \ldots, 4 \}$

$$u_0 = y(0) = 1$$
$$u_1 = u_0 + f(t_0, u_0) \cdot \Delta t = 1 + (2 - 3(1)) \cdot .5 = 1 - .5 = .5$$
$$u_2 = u_1 + f(t_1,u_1) \cdot \Delta t = .5 + (2 - 3(.5)) \cdot .5 = .5 + .25 = .75$$
$$u_3 = u_2 + f(t_2,u_2) \cdot \Delta t = .75 + (2 - 3(.75)) \cdot .5 = .625$$
$$u_4 = u_3 + f(t_3,u_3) \cdot \Delta t = .625 + (2 - 3(.625)) \cdot .5 = .6875$$

This was the first point where I was a little confused. Can the estimated values drop and then increase like they do above?

Then solve the equation and find the initial value of $C$.

$$y'(t) = 2-3y \equiv \dfrac{y'(t)}{2-3y}=1$$
$$\int \dfrac{y'(t)}{2-3y}\ dt = \int dt$$
$$\text{Let $y'(t)\ dt = dy$:}\ \int \dfrac{dy}{2-3y} = \int dt$$
$$\text{Let $u = 2-3y$, $du = -3\ dy$:}\ -\dfrac{1}{3}\int \dfrac{du}{u} = \int dt$$
$$-\dfrac{1}{3} \ln(u) = t + C$$
$$\ln(2 - 3y) = -3(t + C)$$
$$2 - 3y = e^{-3(t+c)}$$
$$-3y = e^{-3(t+C)} - 2$$
$$\text{Hence, } y(t) = \dfrac{2}{3} - \dfrac{e^{-3(t+C)}}{3}$$
$$y(0) = 1 = \dfrac{2}{3} - \dfrac{e^{-3C}}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{3} = -\dfrac{e^{-3C}}{3}$$
$$-1 = e^{-3C}$$
$$\ln(-1) = -3C$$
$$\text{Hence, } C = \dfrac{-i \pi}{3},\ y(t) = \dfrac{2}{3} - \dfrac{e^{-3t}}{3}$$

This was where I got really confused. Transcendental number. I really don't remember doing those in calc II. In fact, the only reason I know that is because I've spent free time reading about complex numbers.

Finally, use the solution for solve for the error in the first part.

$$\text{percent error} = \dfrac{|\text{exact} - \text{approx}|}{\text{exact}} \cdot 100$$
$$\text{percent error} = \dfrac{|0.66584 - 0.6875|}{0.66584} \cdot 100$$
$$\text{percent error} = 3.2530\%$$

Any tips, or pointing out large errors would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!